# theme.js and responsive.js not loading in custom theme in magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, css

I have created a custom theme,

```
   Thomson/
    └── book
        ├── composer.json
        ├── media
        │   └── image.png
        ├── registration.php
        └── theme.xml
```

After that I choose my custom theme via admin, my frontend not load correctly.

I tried, `static-content deploy`, `clear cache`, and remove `<m2>/var/* files`

css are calling but  `theme.js` and `responsive.js` is goes to 404.

**Reference:**

**Error:**

[image]

**Frontend:**

[image]

Suggest me, How to fix this..

Comment: Please share  your theme files.. For a suggestion,pub/static(exclude .htaccess) and **var/view_preprocessed delete

Comment: @AmitBera   I follow  `Magento Spider` answer, now  works fine

Comment: cool,please accept his/her answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions

**Solution 1 -**

You need to define *parent* in your *theme.xml* file, so the that responsive.js and theme.js file will access from the parent theme

theme.xml ( app/design/frontend/Thomson/Book/theme.xml )

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>Thomson Book</title> 
   <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme -->
   <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
   </media>
</theme
```

**Solution 2 -**

You need to add both the files *responsive.js* and *theme.js* in your custom theme.

```
Thomson/
    └── book
        ├── composer.json
        ├── media
        │   └── image.png
        ├── registration.php
        └── theme.xml
        |-- web
             |--js
                 |--responsive.js
                 |--theme.js
```

Comment: But luma theme does not have that js. How is that working?

Comment: I have exactly same issue,  luma theme does not have that js.

Comment: Hey I tried the second solution but not working.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that it was constantly loading `theme.js` from the parent theme instead of the child theme even with cache cleaning..

I solved it by manually removing the symlink from `pub/static/[...]/theme.js` and doing a static deploy + reloading the page.